# Installing PyQt-gpl-5.5.1 and sip for python 3.4.3+

Tags: python-3.x, python-sip

I'm trying to install eric6-6.1.2 which requires PyQt-gpl-5.5.1 which tells me during

```
python3 configure.py

Error: Make sure you have a working sip on your PATH or use the --sip argument 
to explicitly specify a working sip.
```

How do I install sip for python 3.4.3+?

Comment: Hello. I installed sip for Python3+ using this command: `sudo apt-get install python3-sip`.